# Updating multiple fields in table

Tags: php, mysql

My question is one of what shall I do rather than I should do it.

I am developing a number of online questionairres with many questions and 
therefore many answers in each questionairre.

People can return to the questionaire up until a certain date so one insert and 
many updates are required.

Does one normally check to see if an answer has been changed from when the data was read from the table and only update the changes or just replace all of the data in the table that is represented on the questionairre. For example, if someone just selects radio button 1 instead of 2 on a visit then do I have to update all fields.

Thank you for any help that you can give me.

Justin

Answer (score 0):

No, you may update one column (field) at a time. Using PDO prepared statements, for example,

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

$sql = "UPDATE survey_22 SET question_43=? WHERE user_id=?";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($new_answer, $user_id));
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I would need to identify which fields needed updating. How would I identify which fields these were or do i update all fields?

Comment: @JustinOakley Do you mean "fields" as records (rows) or parts of a record (columns)?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. I would say it's perfectly fine to update all columns at once, even if most (even all) didn't change. That is, it'd be more inefficient to check every field for a change than to simply "clobber" data. The only case where checking would be necessary, is if you don't want the timestamp of the row to be updated if there has been no changes: in that case, you must check all fields regardless.

Comment: Thanks acheong87. If none change then its pointless but working out which have changed is difficult. There is no problem with the timestamp but the issue is on the radar now for future consideration.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can update all the fields as this will not take much longer. What you will save on the not-updating the fields that are not required to update, you will loose on determining them.

Of course some benchmark would be handful, but personally I would update all of them and that's what I always do. You can name it "laziness" but one more advantage is that the code is simpler.

Comment: Thanks Voitcus. I thought so but just nice to know how others do things. Justin